# Remove duplicates from a list of objects without relying on a set

Tags: java, list, set

In java, and there is one catch here. The objects are already compiled and the hash() and equals() methods therefore cannot be over written. Throwing it into a set, then back into a list will not work because the criteria for uniqueness isn't currently defined in equals() and this cannot be overridden.

Comment: What is your criteria for 'uniqueness' which is not defined in the equals() method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should still be able to create subclasses and create `equals` and `hashcode` methods that work, unless the classes/methods are `final`.

If that is the case, you could use composition, basically create a wrapper for the things you are putting in the collection, and have the wrapper's `equals` and `hashcode` implement the contract correctly, for the thing being wrapped.

You are in a tough position, because what I am reading is that the original classes are not following the contract for `equals` and `hashcode` which is a real problem in Java.  It's a pretty serious bug.

Comment: The point being that if comparison is cheaper, the TreeSet approach may be better. the original question did not say anything about having a good hashcode.

Comment: If you have a good hashcode as well, you can also use containment; i.e. use a wrapper rather than a subclass.

Answer (score 1):

Write a custom [Comparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) for your objects and use [Collections.sort()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) to sort your list. And then remove duplicates by going though a list in a loop.

Comment: ... or use the `Comparator` with a `TreeSet`

Answer (score 1):

a `compareTo` method would return `-1`, `0`, `1`; if `0`, remove from list.